# Problems to extract feed from Facebook group with Power Query

Tags: facebook, powerquery

After the upgrade of Graph API to 2.2, I can't extract the feed from the Facebook Group that I'm admin for.

I can extract Members, but nothing else. This function worked earlier this year:

```
= Facebook.Graph("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/189530894403791/Feed")
```

And the result: `This table is empty`.

Comment: please be more specific. what access token are you using? are you the owner of the app? did you debug the token and does it include the correct permissions?

Comment: When I use Graph Api everything works. In Excel Power Query only extracting all the groups members works. 

So there is something wrong with the connection when extract data through Excel Power Query. 

What I know I can't put in a Token in Excel Power Query.

Comment: so what about the access token? is it correct? which one are you using? app token? user token? is it a public group?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group/feed#read

Comment: It's a closed group. And since it works in Graph API Explorer, I guess it's the correct token.

Comment: I'm not working in any app, I'm just downloading data into excel.

Comment: well, in that case please look at the link i posted. all permissions you need are explained in there. make sure you get to know all the different tokens and know how to use them too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is no longer possible. As of the API upgrade, Power Query no longer has permissions to grant "user_group" or "user_managed_groups" access to end users. More details on those recent changes can be found here: https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/571845-3rd-party-service-facebook-connector.